# can i refresh array after using splice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

if i unchecked Monday and Wednesday my target output is only Tues,Thurs,Fri but my output is Wed,Thurs,Fri

```
 $('#update_shift').click(function(){

        if(day.has('M')){
            // remove in array
            if( $('#moncheck').prop('checked') == false ) {
                // remove data in array
                var a = work.indexOf('M');
                console.log(a);
                     work.splice(work[a], 5);
            }
        }

        else{
            // push data in array
            if( $('#moncheck').prop('checked') == true ) {
                var m1 = $('#Monday_1').val();
                var m2 = $('#Monday_2').val();
                var m3 = $('#Monday_3').val();

                if ($('#Monday_4').val() == "" ) {
                   var m4 = "0";
                     work.push('M');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }
                else{
                   var m4 = $('#Monday_4').val();
                     work.push('M');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }

            }

        }

        if(day.has('T')){
            if( $('#tuescheck').prop('checked') == false ) {
                // remove data in array
                var a = work.indexOf('T');
                console.log(a);
                     work.splice(work[a], 5);
            }
        }
        else{
             // push data in array
            if( $('#tuescheck').prop('checked') == true ) {

                 if ($('#Tuesday_4').val() == "" ) {
                   var m1 = $('#Tuesday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Tuesday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Tuesday_3').val();
                   var m4 = "0";
                     work.push('T');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                 }
                 else{
                   var m1 = $('#Tuesday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Tuesday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Tuesday_3').val();
                   var m4 = $('#Tuesday_4').val();
                     work.push('T');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                 }

            }
        }

        if(day.has('W')){
            if( $('#wedcheck').prop('checked') == false ) {
                // remove data in array
                var a = work.indexOf('W');
                console.log(a);
                     work.splice(work[a], 5);
            }
        }
        else{
             // push data in array
            if( $('#wedcheck').prop('checked') == true ) {

                if ($('#Wednesday_4').val() == "" ) {
                   var m1 = $('#Wednesday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Wednesday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Wednesday_3').val();
                   var m4 = "0";
                     work.push('W');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }else{
                   var m1 = $('#Wednesday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Wednesday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Wednesday_3').val();
                   var m4 = $('#Wednesday_4').val();
                     work.push('W');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }

            }
        }

        if(day.has('TH')){
            if( $('#thurscheck').prop('checked') == false ) {
                // remove data in array
                var a = work.indexOf('TH');
                     work.splice(work[a], 5);
            }
        }
        else{
             // push data in array
            if( $('#thurscheck').prop('checked') == true ) {

                if ($('#Thursday_4').val() == "" ) {
                   var m1 = $('#Thursday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Thursday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Thursday_3').val();
                   var m4 = "0";
                     work.push('TH');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }else{
                   var m1 = $('#Thursday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Thursday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Thursday_3').val();
                   var m4 = $('#Thursday_4').val();
                     work.push('TH');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }

            }
        }

        if(day.has('F')){
            if( $('#fricheck').prop('checked') == false ) {
                // remove data in array
                var a = work.indexOf('F');
                     work.splice(work[a], 5);
            }
        }
        else{
             // push data in array
            if( $('#fricheck').prop('checked') == true ) {

                if ($('#Friday_4').val() == "" ) {
                   var m1 = $('#Friday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Friday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Friday_3').val();
                   var m4 = "0";
                     work.push('F');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }else{
                   var m1 = $('#Friday_1').val();
                   var m2 = $('#Friday_2').val();
                   var m3 = $('#Friday_3').val();
                   var m4 = $('#Friday_4').val();
                     work.push('F');
                     work.push(m1);
                     work.push(m2);
                     work.push(m3);
                     work.push(m4);
                }
            }
        }


            console.log(work);
        });
```

**console log sample output**

[image: console log sample output]

if i splice monday 0 to 4 index and wednesday 10 to 14 but in the other pic 0 to 4 and 5 to 9 is removed. can i refresh the indexing of data after splice in the array?

**this is the console if i remove monday and wednesday**

[image: this is the console if i remove monday and wednesday]

Comment: updated with inline image

Comment: `.splice()` mutates (changes) the original array. `.slice()`  returns a copy of the original array. Replace `.splice()` with `.slice()`.

Comment: @zer00ne except that slice is a completely different operation to splice